# Query and ImportRange with Dynamic Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have 2 sheets which are connected.

Sheet-1: Has ID column and Status column (Status field is manually updated by the team)

Sheet-2: Has ID column and Status column (+ many other fields)

Requirement: Status column in Sheet 2 to be updated from Sheet-1 if ID column in sheet-2 = ID column in Sheet-1

I wrote a Query and ImportRange, but I could find Query working only when I compare it against a static value (for e.g. Yes). What I want is it to check against the value in ID column from both the sheets and import only for rows that match.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZkPaYb1IIIkcbVerdmZ-Ru1vxFu1YMWj74QNQj2jles", "Ops Action Sheet!B2:B10000"),"select Col2 where Col1 = 'Yes'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question about using `QUERY`, but I believe that that function might not be the best tool for what you're trying to do.

I write below a solution using the alternative function `VLOOKUP`.

I am assuming here that by "Sheet-1" and "Sheet-2", you actually mean entirely different spreadsheets, judging by your use of `IMPORTRANGE`.

If you don't mind having a copy of Sheet-1's contents living within Sheet-2, here is what you can do:

1. On a new sheet (tab) in Sheet-2, copy this function (fill in `sheet_1_url`):

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet_1_url", "Ops Action Sheet!$A:$B")
```

2. You should see a copy of the data from Sheet-1 in that tab. You can hide this tab or protect it if you wish.
3. On your main data tab within Sheet-2, copy this formula in your Status column (assuming that your `ID` is in **A2**:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,range_from_step_1,2,),)
```

4. Copy that formula down as much as you need.

---

However, if you don't want to have a copy of Sheet-1's data in Sheet-2 for whatever reason, you can simply skip steps 1-2 above, going straight to step 3, with the following formula in Sheet-2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("sheet_1_url", "Ops Action Sheet!$A:$B"),2,),)
```

Not that I recommend it, since you'd technically be importing your data virtually within the formula *N* number of times, which will be a huge performance hit.

You can see the references for the formulas used above here:

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

edit to reflect and paste in spreadsheet 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet!A:C"), {2, 3}, 0)))
```

`A2:A` - column of IDs in spreadsheet 2
`Sheet!A:C` - column A of this range hosts IDs
`{2, 3}` - brings column B and C from spreadsheet 1 into spreadsheet 2